# For loop appears to skip certain items in list

Tags: python, pyodbc, openpyxl

I've been working on a project using pyodbc that pulls a list of family names from our database and then iteratively pulls data about each family from subsequent tables, and writes it in a spreadsheet. This is a condensed version that shows the idea.

```
def Run(Family):
    names = []

    con = pyodbc.connect("...")
    cursor = con.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT ... ")
    for item in cursor:
        names.append(item[0])
        #print(item[0], 1)

    for name in names:
        cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT <data> FROM <tables> WHERE name = ?", name)
        for item in cursor:
            #print(item[0], 2)
            name = item[0]
            age = item[1]
            income = item[2]
            etc...

        <Write to spreadsheet>
```

The problem I'm having is that the loop seems to skip over a certain name in the list. While investigating I found that the first (commented) print statement does print the name, but somewhere between there and the second print statement, it disappears.

The odd part is if I place another print statement down below where I am writing to the spreadsheet, the name is back, but because it didn't go through the second cursor it's data wasn't pulled so the spreadsheet just displays the name with all of the info from the name before.

I've been trying to figure out what's going on but really can't see anything that would cause this. Please let me know with any ideas or any other information that might be helpful. Thanks!

**Update1:** I fixed the iterator name as you suggested but this did not fix the issue with it leaving out a name. As I noted it was not every name that did this, just a certain one every time.

**Update2:** I also fixed the query as you suggested, although sql injection should not be a threat in this case since "name" is not being entered by a user, but is pulled from another field in the same database, which is managed solely by other members of my team.

Comment: Instead of `cursor.execute('... name = ' + name)` you should do `cursor.execute('... name = ?', name)`. (may require changing `?` to something else depending on the backend. check the documentation for `pyodbc`). If you don't do this your code can be subject to SQL injection. If someone enters a name like `''; DROP TABLE ...` you'd loose data running your code.

Comment: Instead of building a SELECT string, you might try following the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) for passing parameters - ```cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT <data> FROM <tables> WHERE name = ?", name)```.  As mentioned below, from your example it looks like ```name``` has not been assigned a *value*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I figured out the issue was actually within the SQL statement, not the Python portion. One of the values in the trouble family was NULL, and because I'm new to SQL I had only used 'join' instead of 'left join', which returned the entire cursor empty instead of just that field.

Comment: they're are also issues with you python code. This isn't really an answer

Comment: If there* are issues in the python, I can fix them, but they weren't what caused the issue. This is what solved the problem I was having, therefore it's the correct answer the way the question was presented.

Comment: Ok true But this question and answer is now very specific to you're exact db. i.e. noone will learn anything from viewing this page

Answer (score 2):

your problem is using the variable name "item" in a loop and then its nested loop. try renameing item to something else like this

```
def Run(Family):
    names = []

    con = pyodbc.connect("...")
    cursor = con.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT ... ")
    for item in cursor:
        names.append(item[0])
        #print(item[0], 1)

    for item in names:
        cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT <data> FROM <tables> WHERE name = " + item)
        for family_data in cursor:
            #print(family_data[0], 2)
            name = item
            age = family_data[1]
            income = family_data[2]
            etc...

        <Write to spreadsheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

For this portion:

```
for item in names:
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT <data> FROM <tables> WHERE name = " + name)
    for item in cursor:
```

I'm pretty sure you meant

```
for name in names:
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT <data> FROM <tables> WHERE name = " + name)
    for item in cursor:
```

Note that I changed the first iterator from `item` to `name`. You were calling both `item`.